# Expired password in OAuth2 and Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Security OAuth2 to implement username/password authorization. The problem is that the error in case of invalid password and expired password is the same: 'invalid_grant'.

I want that the clients of my API can distinguish between both cases and act accordingly. If the password is invalid, ask for password again. If the password is expired, ask to change the password.

Is there any better way than to check the error_description (which is different in both cases)?